# Running WSGI application with a different version of Django to what's installed in python site-packages?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-wsgi

I have an application that uses Django 1.3 installed in python's site-packages. I want to create another copy of it (WSGI under Apache) but make it use a newer version of Django I've unpacked alongside to see if any input is required before I'm able to migrate to 1.4.

Is there a way to somehow specify where WSGI should import Django from?

Comment: Here's an article that's [meant to help beginners with virtualenv](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19725807220/django-pinax-virtualenv-setuptools-pip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the app inside a virtualenv.

Comment: I wish I could +10 this answer in one shot.

Comment: For which mod_wsgi documentation covers it in http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments

Comment: it's probably a good solution yet I just moved Django out of python site-packages and each of the sites is referencing its own Django version I unpacked alongside.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use virtualenv and run uwsgi in it. [virtualenv-apache-mod_wsgi](http://www.foxhop.net/django-virtualenv-apache-mod_wsgi)